# "error": "Index not defined, add ".indexOn"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have created a database in Firebase which looks like:

[image: database structure]

Now I go into a REST client and issue this query:

```
https://movielens3.firebaseio.com/movieLens/users.json?orderBy="age"&startAt=25&print=pretty
```

It gives me an error:

```
"error": "Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "age", for path "/movieLens/users", to the rules"
```

So I go in the rule section and define this rule:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users" : {
          ".indexOn": ["age", "gender", "occupation", "zipCode"]
        },
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're defining indexes for `/users`. There is no child node `users` straight under the root of your tree, so those indexes will be empty.

Since you query `/movieLens/users`, that's exactly where the index has to be defined:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "movieLens": {
            "users" : {
                ".indexOn": ["age", "gender", "occupation", "zipCode"]
            },
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true
        }
    }
}
```

**Update for problem in the comments:**

You're storing the user's age as a string, so cannot filter them as a number. The solution is to fix your data and store it as a number.

But in the meantime this query somewhat works:

```
https://movielens3.firebaseio.com/movieLens/users.json?orderBy="age"&equalTo="35"
```

In JavaScript:

```
ref
  .orderByChild('age')
  .startAt('35')
  .limitToFirst(3)
  .once('value', function(s) { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val(), null, '  ')); 
  }, function(error) { 
    if(error) console.error(error); 
  })
```

The "somewhat" being that it does a lexical sort, not a numerical one. Fix the data for a real solution.

Note that you're also ignoring Firebase [guidance on structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) by storing the data as an array. This was already causing problems for me in the REST API, which is why I dropped the `print=pretty`. I *highly* recommend that you read the [Firebase programming guide for JavaScript developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) from start to finish and follow the advice in there. The few hours that takes now, will prevent many hours of problems down the line.

Comment: it solves the problem but the query `https://movielens3.firebaseio.com/movieLens/users.json?orderBy="age"&startAt=25&print=pretty` doesn't filter anything. it returns all the records

Comment: You're storing your age as a string. Not a good idea. I'd also *seriously* consider creating custom indexes (just lookup lists that you maintain), because you'll run into performance problems quickly without those. See this blog post: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html and this article: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/