# How to update child node (password) with the help of user entered phone number in firebase using android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the Firebase view. Password is updating under users, I want to update it under sidd5(userHelper class)->Password with the help of user-entered phone number.

[**Firebase Database img**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pc55.jpg)

**Here is the code.**

```js
public void updatePassword(View view) {
            //get data from fields
            String userNewPassword = newPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
            String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");


            //update data in firebase
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
            reference.child(phoneNumber).getRef().getParent().child("password").setValue(userNewPassword);

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForgetPassSuccess.class));
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: So you need to update the password property of "sidd5", right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes Sir

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a user with a specific phone number in the Firebase Realtime Database, you need to use a Query object. Once you have found it, then you can simply update the "password" property using "setValue()" method. Assuming that "phone" property holds the exact value that exists under `users/sidd5/password`, which is "+9.......01", please try the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
Query queryByPhone = usersRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phoneNumber);
queryByPhone.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                userSnapshot.child("password").getRef().setValue(userNewPassword);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting error at '.get()' as Cannot resolve method get in Query. @AlexMamo

Comment: In that case, please update Firebase Realtime Database dependency to the [latest available version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) and tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes it did work. But my password is not updating in Database. It is showing as follows **I/RepoOperation: get for query /users falling back to disk cache after error: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "phone", for path "/users", to the rules
D/NewPassword: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "phone", for path "/users", to the rules**. @AlexMamo

Comment: Have you tried add the [indexOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968413/error-index-not-defined-add-indexon)? Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes now it's updating in password section. Thank you sir for giving your precious time. @AlexMamo